# Get all crossing LineStrings in GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a GeoDataFrame with LineString geometries. My goal is to keep all lines that intersect (or fork) but do NOT cross each other. The GeoDataFrame is very big, therefore it should be performant.

*unary_union* cannot be used because it also splits the crossing ones.

I created a custom function but this seems to be too slow for large datasets. It also filters out the black line that is crossed by the red line, which is wrong:

```
crossing_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=data.columns)
    def determine_crossing_ways(row):
        for i, other_row in data.iterrows():
            if other_row.name != row.name:
                # Compare the two rows
                crossing = row.geometry.crosses(other_row.geometry)
                if crossing:
                    crossing_df.loc[len(crossing_df)] = row
                    crossing_df.loc[len(crossing_df)] = other_row

    data.apply(determine_crossing_ways, axis=1)
```

I also tried to make use of the *crossing* function of GeoPandas but this does not work, the result is zero.

```
data = gpd.read_file("data.geojson")
crossing = data.geometry.crosses(data.geometry) # red line
intersecting = data[~data.geometry.isin(crossing)] # black lines
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the GeoPandas index (see [GeoPandas issue: Add example or implement dissolve of contiguous or otherwise related geometries](https://giters.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1715) for example)

[image]

Crosses (red line):

```
print(list(data.index)
[0, 1, 2, 3]
heads, tails = data.sindex.query_bulk(data.geometry, predicate="crosses")
ix = heads != tails
heads = heads[ix]
tails = tails[ix]
print(list(zip(heads, tails))) 
[(0, 1), (1, 0)]
```

Intersects (all lines)

```
 heads, tails = data.sindex.query_bulk(data.geometry, predicate="intersects")
 ix = heads != tails
 heads = heads[ix]
 tails = tails[ix]
 print(list(zip(heads, tails))) 
 [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 3), (3, 2)]
```

Touches (green lines):

```
heads, tails = data.sindex.query_bulk(data.geometry, predicate="touches")
ix = heads != tails
heads = heads[ix]
tails = tails[ix]
print(list(zip(heads, tails))) 
[(0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 3), (3, 2)]
```

But be careful with the floating point precision problem ([How to deal with rounding errors in Shapely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28036167/835653), [Determine if Shapely point is within a LineString/MultiLineString](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21295192/835653) for example), specifically for `touches`. In your figure, the line 3 intersects and crosses the line 2

#### New

To map this result to the rows in the dataframe use `loc` or `iloc` ([Pandas Select Rows by Index (Position/Label)](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-select-rows-by-index/))

Crossing lines:

```
heads, tails = data.sindex.query_bulk(data.geometry, predicate="crosses")
heads # index of GeoDataFrame
[0,1]
data.iloc[heads]
   id                                           geometry
0   0  LINESTRING (142.405 -54.279, 142.641 -199.619,...
1   1  LINESTRING (71.474 -288.404, 165.719 -294.356,...
```

Modify the original GeoDataFrame

```
data.loc[data.index[heads], 'cross'] = 1
print(data)
   id                                           geometry  cross
0   0  LINESTRING (142.405 -54.279, 142.641 -199.619,...    1.0
1   1  LINESTRING (71.474 -288.404, 165.719 -294.356,...    1.0
2   2  LINESTRING (142.641 -199.619, 206.686 -151.562...    NaN
3   3  LINESTRING (206.686 -151.562, 208.873 -104.378...    NaN
```

Comment: How can I map this result to the rows in the data frame?

Comment: sse New in my answer

Comment: This works very well except for very few linestring. There it does not find the touching points. Maybe this is related to the floating precisions. But how can I tackle this with query_bulk?